# How to take sample from a dataset keeping same class balance?

Tags: dataset, sample, sampling

I am working on with https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html dataset.
It has two columns. one is a review of one or two lines. Second is rating, which is number between 0 and 4. The total number of entries is 8533. Data is distributed as follows:

- rating ,count of examples for that rating
- 3,                      2318
- 1,                      2215
- 2,                      1623
- 4,                      1287
- 0,                      1090

Now, I want to take a sample from this dataset of size say 10, 20, 30 and so on. Each time I want to keep the class distribution same as in original dataset. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Stratified Sampling, it's standard problem with many existing solutions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250273/benefits-of-stratified-vs-random-sampling-for-generating-training-data-in-classi